# Cannot mount NFS

Tags: centos7, nfs, network-share, debian-jessie

I'd like to share a particular directory inside /home between a CentOS 7 and a Debian 8 machine. The CentOS 7 machine would work as NFS server and the debian as the client.

What I've done so far:

1)On CentOS:

```
$ mkdir /var/nfsshare
$ chmod -R 755 /var/nfsshare
$ chown nfsnobody:nfsnobody /var/nfsshare
$ vim /etc/exports # Add the following
/var/nfsshare    10.1.0.X(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
$ systemctl restart nfs-server
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=nfs
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=mountd
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=rpc-bind
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

2) On debian:

```
$ mkdir -p /home/user/nfsshare
$ mount -t nfs 10.1.1.Y:/var/nfsshare /home/user/nfsshare
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Does anyone know what may be failing?

Thanks

Comment: Attempt to connect to yourself locally on CentOS to prove that the NFS server is working.

Answer (score 0):

You probably also should allow portmapper, port 111.